# Pip EnvironmentError - Cannot upgrade package

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to update a package using pip through the command:

```
pip install [package name] --upgrade
```

I am receiving the following error and am not sure how to get around it:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this and upgrade my package?

Comment: try this ```pip install "packagename" --upgrade --user```

Comment: This sounds like an OS user access control issue. Is your python installed as an administrator? If it is, you probably need to sudo the pip install or admin prompt it (if in windows)

Comment: @HozayfaElRifai Perfect thanks that worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permission error.

Suggested way:

Do it in your user environment:

> pip install [package name] --upgrade --user

You can do it again with escalated privilege.

In Unix(Linux,OSX,BSD,...) environment do it with:

> sudo pip install [package name] --upgrade

or in Windows you should run it as adminstrator.